# meaning of "add to"

Tags: meaning

In the dictionary, "add to" means "to make (something) larger, better, or greater": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/add%20to
So, can I understand the below like: there are tens of thousands already unemployed in the IT industry, and Google's layoff today makes their number larger?
It comes at a news clip, https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20230121_100600_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20230121_100600_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=616/676&exact=1&ignore=x.mp4

> Google today joined a growing list of tech giants scaling back, **adding
> to** the tens of thousands of workers in the industry who find
> themselves unemployed.

Comment: You can't say they're "unemployed" **by** the companies that laid them off. They just *are* "unemployed".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean "umemployed" is only used as an adjective and that "umempoly" is not used as a verb?

Comment: @JiHyunLee Can you find the verb "unemploy" in dictionaries? (Onelook.com is a good resource for free online dictionaries.)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I refined my post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. ["Add to" can also mean:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/add-to)

> to make an amount or number greater by adding another amount or number